# solr: how can I get the number of keywords in the whole corpus?

Tags: solr

I'm doing a research about PMI using an engine which is established by solr. I want to get the number of keywords within the corpus(not the numofDocs). Is there a direct way to get this?
Another Question:
Can I do a search which contains a logic operater(such as NEAR) in solr system? OR similary method to do this?

Comment: What do you mean, "the number of keywords within the corpus"? Could you please clarify? Do you mean the number of matching keywords for a particular document? or the number of matching keywords in all the documents returned? or the total number of keywords in matching documents?

Comment: I mean the number of matching keywords in all the documents.

Comment: Ah so if a document is matched, you want to know how many words in the document matched the search? and then do the same for each document that matches? Offhand I don't know of any direct method to do that. What you might try is using highlighting with `&hl.fragsize=0` (returns the whole document!) and then parsing the data returned (getting a count of the word boundaries within the highlight tags, adding 1).

Answer (score 2):

`NEAR` is "proximity search"; solr provides something similar in the form of "[sloppy phrase queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_one_term_near_another_term_.28say.2C_.22batman.22_and_.22movie.22.29)", which have the form:

```
field:"phrase of words"~10
```

The `10` is how close the words in the phrase must be.